# Adobe flex how to set width & height of spark application or layout

Tags: flash, actionscript, flex4

How to do this using flex 4.6 spark templating to set the width and height of the application?

Answer (score 0):

Put them into your Main MXML file like:

```
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                   xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                   xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"                    
                   closing="appClosing(event)"                     
                   width="1280" height="720"                      
                   >
</s:WindowedApplication>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want your application to take up the entire browser window you will include the following attributes in your topmost MXML tag:

```
width="100%"
height="100%"
```